# Android app requires clean after editing string resources

Tags: android, build, resources

I am developing an Android app with Eclipse in Win 7.
When I edit the value of a string resource in an xml file, then press F11 to start debugging, Eclipse asks me if I want to save the modified file, then runs the old app without recompiling the resource.
If I edit the resource and a source .java file, the .java file is recompiled, but the resource editing is ignored.
The only workaround that I found is to clean and rebuild.
I tried to check the 'Refresh on access' option as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071563/eclipse-android-wont-clean-wont-refresh-resources) (it was unchecked), but it didn't help.

Comment: Check this options       Eclipse-> Project -> Build Automatically

Comment: I already tried, as suggested by the [answer](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/news/images/lightweight_refresh_by_default.png) of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071563/eclipse-android-wont-clean-wont-refresh-resources), but it didn't help